# Why Command's stdin write_all never terminate?

Tags: rust, terminal

I have the following code. It runs `python3 solution.py` whose `stdin` is supplied from variable `input`

```
let mut cmd = Command::new("python3");
let mut child = cmd
    .stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .arg("solution.py")
    .spawn()
    .expect("Failed to execute solution");
println!("Writing to stdin");
child
    .stdin
    .as_mut()
    .unwrap()
    .write_all(input.as_bytes())
    .unwrap();

//never printed
println!("Finish writing to stdin");

child.stdin.as_mut().unwrap().flush().unwrap()
```

It always runs ok (and terminates fast) when the `input` variable is small. But when it is ~3MB (large String), it never terminates. I guess there is deadlock somewhere since the CPU usage is small.

Could you suggest how to make it run with large `input`? And why does it seem to suffer from deadlock?

**Update**

Simplified version of `solution.py` where this problem still happens (it just prints whitespace strings):

```
t = int(input())
for tt in range(t):
    input()
    res = [' '] * 1000
    result = ''.join(res)
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(tt+1, result))
```

Interestingly, if I change line 4 to the below, the program terminates

```
    res = [' '] * 100
```

It is probably due to large output size?

Comment: What is in `solution.py`

Comment: I think `solution.py` doesn't really matter. Since `python3 solution.py < input.txt` terminates (`inputs.txt` is the same as the `input` variable).

Comment: But understood your point. Let me quickly try changing `solution.py` to be a just simple line counting program...

Comment: It does matter. If your script is reading stdin and writing stdout in an overlapping way, then it is evident why the deadlock occurs: you are not reading the stdout on Rust side and thus script waits to print the results forever. Command line redirection, e.g. `< input.txt`) does *not* behave equivalently to your Rust code.

Comment: Thx, I have updated the question with `solution.py` code. It seems, it's due to large output size?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69528953/701589 answers it correctly. It turns out the buffer is full (piled up by write_all to stdin, yet the stdout is never read).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Rust program is writing to a pipe connected to the stdin of the child process. The child process is writing to its stdout, which is again a pipe. The operating system is buffering some amount data for both pipes, but when the buffer is full it will wait for the process on the reading end to consume the data before accepting any further writes.

The `write_all()` call is constantly writing data into the stdin pipe, which is read by the child process. The child process is writing data to its stdout pipe, but nobody is consuming that data. once the stdout pipe buffer fills up, the child process blocks trying to write further data, so it stops reading data from stdin. That means the stdin pipe buffer will also fill up, at which point the parent process also blocks while trying to write further data.

The easiest way to resolve this is moving writing to the stdin pipe to a thread, and adding code in the main thread to read from stdout. This way, your Rust program reads and writes data in parallel, and no deadlock will occur. The [documentation of `std::process` has an example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/index.html#handling-io) demonstrating this approach.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer explains the underlying issue and gives the directions how to solve it using the standard library.

In addition to that, you can use the [`subprocess`](https://crates.io/crates/subprocess) crate whose [`communicate()`](https://docs.rs/subprocess/0.2.8/subprocess/struct.Popen.html#method.communicate) method (modeled after Python's [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)) is designed to prevent deadlocks in situations like yours:

```
let (out, _) = subprocess::Exec::cmd("python3")
    .arg("solution.py")
    .stdin("some data")
    .communicate()?
    .read_string()?;
// out is a String
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `subprocess`.

Comment: On Linux, `communicate()` uses `epoll()` under the hood, so it works in a single thread. All the major async frameworks (tokio, async-std, smol) offer non-blocking communication with the child process, so they also provide alternative approaches.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, though the use of `libc::poll()` is an optimization under the hood. (It's not used on Windows, and the public API is the same.) The async runtimes make it fairly easy to spawn separate tasks for reading and writing, but it's still not trivial unless you know what you're doing - and it requires non-trivial dependencies. I've now amended the answer to mention that I'm the author of `subprocess`.